# remove amazon pay icon from shipping step

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, phtml, amazon-payment

How do I remove the "amazon pay" icon from the shipping step?
If i set "Configuration"->"Payment Method"=>"Amazon Pay"=>"Advanced"->"Display Amazon Pay Method" to "No", then it'll be removed, but it also remove the Amazon Pay option in the "Review & Payments" step. 
I would like to remove it from the "shipping step" only, how can i achieve that?[image]

Comment: you can remove it by using css if you don't want to show them on checkout page

Comment: If I use css to hidden the button, it also hidden the button on next page (review/payment step). Is there a way to hidden the button for this div ID #checkout-step-shipping  only?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove this UI component via layout using `componentDisabled` property.
Add this to your `checkout_index_index.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="amazon-button-region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: OMG!!!! What a lot of code

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre defined setting available in the module itself.
You need to overwrite the html file by creating custom module.

Vendor Name: Kris
Module Name: Wen

File: Kris/Wen/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Amazon_Payment/template/checkout-button.html': 
              'Kris_Wen/template/checkout-button.html'
        }
    }
}
```

File: Kris/Wen/view/frontend/web/template/checkout-button.html

```
<!-- Removed AmazonPay Button -->
```

This will overwrite the default module template and will hide the button on checkout screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe the button load dynamically to both shipping step & review/payment step. If I use css to hidden the button, it also hidden the button on next page (checkout). Is there a way to hidden the button for this div ID #checkout-step-shipping only?

Comment: The section you want to hide only appears on shipping step  by default. That html is not any ways showing in review/payment step. So above code would work for you sa it is not playing with css but code block. Try and check.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't' work.  if I remove/override the Amazon button from the template file. It will also remove the button from the checkout step, will disable customer to checkout through amazon.